# Where can I complain about the quality of a T-shirt I purchased from the SE store?

Tags: support, shop, t-shirt, merchandise

Where can I complain about the quality of a T-shirt I purchased from the SE store? Of course, I am not interested in idle lamenting. I would like to complain to whomever is in a position to provide a relevant response to my complaint.

P.S.
I tagged the question with [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) since I assume that the shop does not sell low quality merchandise on purpose and that I have been rather unlucky to stumble upon it.

Comment: Voted to close because I don't think that Meta handles shop issues. Please write an E-Mail to `team@stackexchange.com` or towards any other contact information you may have received with the delivery/bill/order.

Comment: I guess the proper way is emailing the team - team@stackoverflow.com

Comment: Guys, your comments qualify as answers to my question. I did not know that I should email somewhere, that is why I have asked the question in the first place.

Comment: @Padded Meta is the right place to ask questions about the shop, which is why we have a [meta-tag:shop] tag. Pretty much any question about Stack Exchange is on-topic here.

Comment: @waiwai933: Then maybe the FAQ should be changed to include the Shop explicitly, or at least partially? Because I don't think Order/Shipping issues and similar would belong here.

Comment: I removed the `bug` tag because it mislabels the post as an issue for the developers. This is a support issue.

Comment: on meta, apparently

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In accordance with the [shop info page](http://shop.stackexchange.com/pages/ordering), you should email shop@stackexchange.com.

Comment: Good catch! :-)

Comment: Damn it...I read that site, but completely missed that part. :(

Comment: Where exactly on the page referred by the link one can see this information?

Comment: @mark "Email us at shop (at) stackexchange (.) com for support or for answers to any questions not here" is right above the sizing table.

Comment: Oh, I see. I was looking for the @ symbol. Forgot about the antispamming measures...

Comment: @mark Yeah, I think it's a bit silly for them to do that. Surely they can handle some spam.

Comment: .. get gmail to host the email, their anti-spam is _eerily_ good. Conspiracy-theory-spawning good.

Comment: @sarnold Apart from not using "not phishing" and "not spam" markers.  I've been trying to stop a particular newsletter from going to spam for months :/

Comment: @Matthew: After finding a few false positives, I no longer think of Gmail's antispam as "eerily good" -- just better than whatever I had cobbled together in the past. :(